# Let $X\subset \mathbb{R^m}$ be a bounded subset. Prove that every uniformly continuous $f: X\rightarrow M$ is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, proof-writing

> Let $X\subset \mathbb{R^m}$ be a bounded subset. Prove that every uniformly continuous function $f: X\rightarrow M$ is bounded.

The book gives a hint: given a decomposition of $\mathbb{R^m}$ in "cubes" of small edge, express $X$ as a finite union.

That's clearly a generalization of the same proof for the case of $X\subset \mathbb{R}$, where we could express $X$ as a finite union of intervals. Since $f$ was uniformly continuous, then its restriction to every subinterval would also be uniformly continuous, and by a good choice of $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ we could come up with a conclusion that $f(X)$ does have a bounded diameter.

But the problem is that i'm not very used to do analysis in $\mathbb{R^m}$. So it's not so clear how to express this decomposition and even why it is possible. Can someone please turn things more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could manage to find an answer. Can someone please tell me if its good?

Attempt:

Given $\epsilon=1$, since $f$ is uniformly continuous, one can find $\delta>0$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$ implies $d(f(x),f(y))<1$, for any $x,y\in X$.

We write a decomposition of $\mathbb{R^m}$ into cubes of edge less than $\delta/\sqrt n$. Since $X$ is bounded, only a finite number of those cubes cover up all $X$, say $X_1,\dots, X_k$.  Given any $x,y\in X$, consider the line $r$ which joins them and let $p$ be the number of points of the intersection of $r$ with the cubes that cover $X$, and write $a_1,\dots, a_p$. We note that $p\leq nk$.  If $p =0$, it is clear that $|x-y|<\delta$, and therefore $d(f(x),f(y))<1$. If $p>0$, then

$d(f(x),f(y))\leq d(f(x),f(a_1))+\dots+d(f(a_p),f(y))\leq 1+\dots+1\leq nk$

which shows that $f(X)$ is a set whose diameter is less than $nk$, by the arbitrary choice of $x,y\in X$. Therefore, $f$ is bounded.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know each of the following statements?

1. Each uniformly continuous $f : X \to M$ extends to a (uniformly) continuous $\overline{f} : \overline{X} \to M$, where $\overline{X}$ denotes the closure of $X$.
2. If $X \subset \Bbb{R}^m$ is bounded, then $\overline{X}$ is compact.
3. Each continuous function on a compact set is bounded.

If so, you should be able to prove your claim.

If not, try to prove each of the claims from above.

---

Alternatively, you could use that for arbitrary $\delta > 0$, a bounded set $X \subset \Bbb{R}^m$ can be covered by finitely many balls of radius $\delta$, i.e., $X \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^M B_\delta (x_i)$ for certain $x_1,\dots, x_M \in \Bbb{R}^m$ (essentially, this is the same as compactness of $\overline{X}$). Now, since $f$ is uniformly continuous, for $\varepsilon = 1$, there is some $\delta > 0$ such that if $|x-y| < 2\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(y)|<1$. Do you see how you can combine these claims to get what you want?

I think this is what the hint in your book is referring to: If you replace the balls from above by cubes, you can write $\Bbb{R}^m = \bigcup_{k \in \Bbb{Z}^m} (\delta' k + [0,\delta']^m)$, and since $X$ is bounded, only finitely many of these cubes will intersect $X$. This shows that $X$ can be covered by finitely many cubes all of side length $\delta' > 0$. By using that each cube of sidelength $\delta' = \delta / \sqrt{m}$ is contained in a ball of radius $\delta$, you get the claim concerning the balls.

Comment: One better use cubes of side length $<\frac \delta{\sqrt n}$, so that $|x-y|<\delta$ for all $x,y$ in the cube